# ReentrantReadWriteLock - many readers at a time, one writer at a time?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, reentrantreadwritelock

I'm somewhat new to multithreaded environments and I'm trying to come up with the best solution for the following situation:

I read data from a database once daily in the morning, and stores the data in a HashMap in a Singleton object.  I have a setter method that is called only when an intra-day DB change occurs (which will happen 0-2 times a day).

I also have a getter which returns an element in the map, and this method is called hundreds of times a day.

I'm worried about the case where the getter is called while I'm emptying and recreating the HashMap, thus trying to find an element in an empty/malformed list.  If I make these methods synchronized, it prevents two readers from accessing the getter at the same time, which could be a performance bottleneck. I don't want to take too much of a performance hit since writes happen so infrequently.  If I use a ReentrantReadWriteLock, will this force a queue on anyone calling the getter until the write lock is released?  Does it allow multiple readers to access the getter at the same time?  Will it enforce only one writer at a time?

Is coding this just a matter of...

```
private final ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private final Lock read = readWriteLock.readLock();
private final Lock write = readWriteLock.writeLock();

public HashMap getter(String a) {
    read.lock();
    try {
        return myStuff_.get(a);            
    } finally {
        read.unlock();
    }
}

public void setter() 
{
    write.lock();
    try {
        myStuff_ = // my logic
     } finally {
          write.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another way to achieve this (without using locks) is the copy-on-write pattern. It works well when you do not write often. The idea is to copy and replace the field itself. It may look like the following:

```
private volatile Map<String,HashMap> myStuff_ = new HashMap<String,HashMap>();

public HashMap getter(String a) {
    return myStuff_.get(a);
}

public synchronized void setter() {
    // create a copy from the original
    Map<String,HashMap> copy = new HashMap<String,HashMap>(myStuff_);
    // populate the copy
    // replace copy with the original
    myStuff_ = copy;
}
```

With this, the readers are fully concurrent, and the only penalty they pay is a volatile read on myStuff_ (which is very little). The writers are synchronized to ensure mutual exclusion.

Comment: Excellent answer. Note that if you know there is only one writer, you don't need to synchronize `setter()`. Also, if accessing an old Map is not a problem, you wouldn't need `volatile`, since accesses to references are always atomic (but you could be using the old Map for a long time).

Comment: If there is only one writer, synchronization may be skipped. You still need volatile, however, as it establishes happens-before. Without volatile, you would suffer from reordering problems.

Comment: that's why I said "if accessing an old Map is not a problem", and "you could be using the old Map for a long time" :)

Comment: Having a stale reference is one consequence, but reordering can cause more serious problems. Another thread may see the new reference (myStuff_) before the setter operation is complete due to reordering.

Comment: ah, yes, I missed that one. So `volatile` is really needed.

Comment: No side effects of an atomic action are visible until the action is complete.and Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile.so use volatile,can make myStuff_ = copy atomic, and when call getter(String a) is during executing myStuff_ = copy,getter(String a)will block until myStuff_ = copy have completed

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the write lock is held by a thread then other threads accessing the getter method would block since they cannot acquire the read lock. So you are fine here. For more details please read the JavaDoc of ReentrantReadWriteLock - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html

Answer (score 0):

You're kicking this thing off  at the start of the day... you'll update it 0-2 times a day and you're reading it 100s of times per day.  Assuming that the reading is going to take, say 1 full second(a looonnnng time) in an 8 hour day(28800 seconds) you've still got a very low read load.   Looking at the docs for ReentrantReadWriteLock you can 'tweek' the mode so that it will be "fair", which means the thread that's been waiting the longest will get the lock.  So if you set it to be fair, I don't think that your write thread(s) are going to be starved.

### References

[ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)

Comment: Does the code I have included accomplish the multiple reader scenario I described?  I only want to prevent the readers from reading if there happens to be a write currently happening.  There are hundreds of reads per day, but at any given time, they can come in bunches and make 20-30 calls to my getter.